# How to get a highest field value in a table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

If a table "people" contains "name" (varchar) and "birthdate" (date) columns, how to find the oldest/youngest buddy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM buddies
WHERE birthdate = (
  SELECT MAX(birthdate) FROM buddies
)
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT name, birthdate FROM people ORDER BY birthdate ASC LIMIT 1
```

Note that if there are two or more people with the same birthdate only one will be returned.

Comment: This is obviously the right way...for some reason I was conflating this with ORDER BY / GROUP BY, which doesn't always behave as nicely.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include ties

```
SELECT name 
FROM people
where birthdate = (select max(birthdate) FROM people)
```

Answer (score 0):

If a table "people" contains "name" (varchar) and "birthdate" (date) columns, how to find the oldest/youngest buddy?

for oldest

SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY birthdate ASC  LIMIT 1

for youngest

SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY birthdate DESC LIMIT 1