# Getting Last Inserted Id From MySQL in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I want to show the last login id from the database in view > _form.php file.I have made the code in _form.php file like this

```
  <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'id'); ?>
    <?php echo Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertId('Form');?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'id'); ?>
  </div>
```

Here Form is the table and the model name.But Still I am getting  `ID:0`.Where is the wrong part?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436264/ascending-form-numbers-in-yii

Answer (score 9):

All the `last_insert_id` functions (be they PHP wrappers or the native mySQL one) typically refer to the last ID created *using the current database connection.* The last login was probably not created during the same request you are showing the table in, so this method won't work for you.

Use a normal `SELECT` to find out the newest login instead - e.g. by using `ORDER by creationtime DESC LIMIT 1`.

Related: [How to get a highest field value in a table in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695711/how-to-get-a-highest-field-value-in-a-table-in-mysql)

Comment: Is there any other method which can be used in Yii?

Comment: @newuser I think you have to do a normal query with whatever method Yii provides for that purpose

Answer (score 8):

Pekka's answer is good for **common**. But if you want to do that action in `Yii Framework`, try this:

```
$myModel = new $model;
$model -> savel(false);
echo $model->primaryKey; // Prints the last id.
```

Or you may try this too for general solution:

```
Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertID();
```

Finally, I suggest you to check out [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.0/CActiveRecord#primaryKey-detail)

Answer (score 5):

```
$max = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('max(id) as max')->from('TABLENAME')->queryScalar();
```

Just add one to get the next.